# How to remove all annotation pins then add a new one

Tags: ios, annotations, mkmapview

curious if someone can help with one thing:

I'm just trying to tell Xcode that if both "addAnnotation" and "newAnnotation" pins exist on the map at the same time, then to remove the initial "newAnnotation" pin.

My non-working code is below:

```
if ([self.mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation] & [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation] return)
{
    [self.mapView removeAnnotation:newAnnotation];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but any idea how to get Xcode to acknowledge it? It looks like putting 'return' at the end isn't working...

Comment: Looks like there is a slight misunderstanding on how if statement works:  <br/>`if ( logical_expression_is_valid ) do_something;`<br/>
Return has nothing to do there, may be your idea is:<br/> 
`if ([self.mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation] & [self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation])
{
    [self.mapView removeAnnotation:newAnnotation];
    return;
}
`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

thank you for the feedback but i solved it with this:

```
NSArray *existingpoints = mapView.annotations;

if ([existingpoints count])
    [mapView removeAnnotations:existingpoints];
```

Comment: This doesn't do what you initially asked for. It only removed a pin if there is only one pin. If both pins are in the annotation list it does nothing.

Comment: it works for me. i have two different pin types: "add" and "new." because i only have one pin loaded on the map to start (e.g. "new"), it removes that, and I have     [self.mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation]; called immediately after to replace it.

Comment: I can see it works for what you want, but it doesn't do what you asked for, so this question won't be much use to future developers who stumble upon it. Maybe you could reword your question to match the conditions you were actually trying to satisfy: Remove all annotations before adding a new one.

Comment: You might try "if ([existingpoints count]) ..." Just in case there's more than one existing point. Could happen. :-) The change means "if count is nonzero", which is what you really mean, I think. I edited the answer and upvoted.